# Receiving final status code 200 but their are 301-> 302-> 200

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
//myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode
```

for this I'm receiving 200 but actual status codes are 301->302->200
http://brita.com/

Please let me know. Is there any mistake in code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the `HttpWebRequest` automatically follows redirects and only gives you the last status code. If you don't want that you can set the `AllowAutoRedirect` property to false:

```
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url); 
myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
//myHttpWebResponse.StatusCode
```

Note that it will stop after the first request though, you'll have to create a new request manually to follow up the redirects.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but for next request from where I can get Url.

Comment: The `HttpWebResponse` has a `Headers` property that will contain the url